# My first time working with linked lists. Would like some critiques and suggestions on how to fix certain issues

Tags: c, linked-list

The program is for a hotel laundry service. The user puts in their room number, first and last name, and the number of items they want to wash. This information is put into a node in a linked list. In the main menu, the user can add more room requests, update a request, print the requests, or quit the program.

The structure can be defined as

```
struct request{
    int room_number;
    char first[NAME_LEN+1];
    char last[NAME_LEN+1];
    int num_items;
    struct request *next;
};
```

I have run into a few issues with my functions:

1. The append function:

```
/*
APPEND FUNCTION:
Gets the room number, first name, last name, and the number of items the user wants to wash.
Creates a new node and appends it to the end of the linked list.
*/
struct request *append_to_list(struct request *list)
{
 struct request *new_node, *last_node, *search;


    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct request));
    //new_node->next = NULL;

    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory.\n");
        return list;
    }

    //get room number
    printf("Enter room number: ");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->room_number);

    //search to see if the room number already exists in the LL.
    for(search = list; search != NULL; search = search->next)
    {
        if(search->room_number == new_node->room_number)
        {
            printf("Room request already exists. Update request using main menu.");
            return list;
        }
    }

    //get first and last name
     printf("Enter first name: ");
    read_line(new_node->first, NAME_LEN+1);
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    read_line(new_node->last, NAME_LEN+1);

    //get the number of items.
    printf("Enter the number of items you wish to wash: ");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->num_items);

    new_node->next = list;


    //if list is empty, return pointer to newly created linked list.
    if(list == NULL)
    {
        list = new_node;
        return new_node;
    }
    //else add request to the end of the LL and return pointer to the LL.
    else
    {
        last_node = list;
        while(last_node->next!=NULL)
            last_node = last_node->next;
    }
    last_node->next = new_node;


 return list;

}
```

Some issues I have run into are that for some reason I cannot make more than two requests. I get an error and the program crashes.

2. The update function:

```
/*
UPDATE FUNCTION:
User enters their room number and the node containing the room number is updated with the number of items the user wants to add on.
*/
void update(struct request *list)
{


    struct request *search;
    int add_items;

    //ask to enter room num
    printf("Enter room number: ");
    int room;
    scanf("%d\n", &room);

    //find matching room num
    for(search = list; search != NULL; search = search->next)
    {

        if(search->room_number == room)
        {
            //ask to enter num of items to be added and update num of items


            printf("How many items would you like to add: ");
            scanf("%d\n", &add_items);
            search->num_items = search->num_items + add_items;
            search = search->next;
            return;

        }
    }
    //if room num is not found, print a message.
            printf("Could not find request.");
    return;
}
```

An issue I had with this function is that the program will just stop when I enter the room number... It does not crash, it just seems like it gets stuck... Not really sure why.

3. Finally the print function:

```
/*
PRINTLIST FUNCTION:
Prints all the nodes in list.
*/
void printList(struct request *list)
{
  //print room num, first and last name, and num of items for all requests on the list.
    while(list != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", list->room_number);
        printf("%s ", list->first);
        printf("%s ", list->last);
        printf("%d\n ", list->num_items);
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```

My only issue with this function is that it infinitely prints all the nodes without stopping.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have the line `new_node->next = list;`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Joshua - while the title suggests that, the content of the question is that the program described here doesn't work as the programmer intended due to errors they made. It may deserve a typical "StackOverflow is not your personal debugging service ..." but I think that's all.

Comment: @moreON: I'd prefer lack of M in MVCE myself in that case.

Comment: You're leaking memory with "Room request already exists"...

Comment: @Joshua — This question does not belong on Code Review.  Code Review is for the improvement of working code; this code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to decide whether you want `new_node` at the end or the beginning of the list. `list = new_node` puts it at the beginning, the subsequent loop puts it at the end, so you create a cyclic list with no end and your next insert operation gets stuck in an infinite loop. If you want new_node to be at the beginning, you don't need to search for the end. If you want it at the end, then `new_node->next` must be set to NULL, not to `list`.
2. Your `for` loop body only gets executed once because you've got `return` in both arms of your `if` statement.
3. This is probably because of the bullet point 1 above.

Comment: so the first point worked and fixed the 3rd point. The second point is working, however it seems to be calling the scanf function before the printf function for some reason. I will enter the room number and it will be blank, then I will have to enter the number of items THEN it will print the question of how many items I want to add, and then it will end the function. Same thing for the else statement I still have to enter number of items even though the room numbers don't match. It won't update the number of items in this case, but I still have to enter it for some reason.